# animategraphics not working on preview mac

Tags: beamer, mac, viewers, animations, animate

I'm making a beamer presentation and in some slides I put animations in the following way:

```
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=0.7]{10}{tsanim2}{}{}}
```

where "tsanim2" is a pdf file.
I'm using OSX 10.9, I have a MacBook Pro Retina and I'm using Preview to show the presentation. The problem is that Preview is not able to show the animations I put, while, when using Abobe Reader, the animations work perfectly (this means that the LaTex code works). However, the quality of the presentation (images and text definitions) in Adobe Reader is not as good as in Preview.

So, the question is: is there any possibility to make Preview showing the animations in beamer presentation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I think animation produced by the `animate` package only works with Adobe Reader, as is said in Section 2 of the [package documentation](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The manual of `animate` is quite explicit about this, as stated in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147478/animategraphics-not-working-on-preview-mac#comment334660_147478). If you are not satisfied with the text/graphics rendering in Adobe Reader you might want to play with its display settings: go Edit->Preferences->Page Display.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting the reason for this: JavaScript is needed to make the animation work, and only Adobe Reader provides it. (Or at least that is my assumption!)

Comment: @JosephWright. That is correct. (There is some JavaScript support in Foxit, but anims don't work.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I forgot to say that Adobe reader doesn't work fine (i.e., the resolution of the presentation is bad) only in full screen mode, while in others mode it works good. However, this is a problem of Adobe...

Comment: @Franco. Weird, never had resolution problems particularly in full-screen mode.